# How to swipe between cameras using CustomVideoCapturer in OpenTok SDK Android

Tags: android, video, camera, opentok, tokbox

I am using `OpenTok` SDK for `android` and trying to add camera switch between `front` and `rear` camera of the phone. I am able to perform this using default camera capture but I need to implement a `custom video capture` to enable autofocus. However I am having trouble switching between cameras while using the `custom video capture`

Here is a link to the [custom video capture I use](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/blob/master/Custom-Video-Driver/app/src/main/java/com/tokbox/android/tutorials/customvideodriver/CustomVideoCapturer.java).

and this is how i build publisher using `custom video capture`

```
mPublisher = new Publisher.Builder(getActivity())
            .name("publisher")
            .capturer(new CustomVideoCapturer(getActivity()))
            .resolution(Publisher.CameraCaptureResolution.HIGH).build();
```

I use `mPublisher.swapCamera()` or `mPublisher.cycleCamera()` to switch between cameras. they work fine while using `default video capture`.but with `custom video capture` they don't function.

Is there specific method I need to override while using custom video capture ?